# Использование одной переменной в двух Методах

Tags: c#, winforms

Я только начал изучать язык C# и winforms. Решил сделать программу, которая загадывает число, а пользователь должен это число отгадать.

Проблема в том, что одна переменная с рандомным числом должна использоваться в двух private void (button1_click и button2_click), но второй void не видит эту переменную и её значение. Как сделать так, чтобы второй void видел переменную Random_Number и её значение? (Заранее скажу, что я тот ещё чайник)

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guess_the_number
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Random_From = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // Рандом От:
            int Random_Before = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); // Рандом До:
            int Tryes = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text); // Количество попыток

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int Random_Number = rnd.Next(Random_From, Random_Before);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Guess_Number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);

            if (Random_Number > Guess_Number)
            {
                textBox6.Text = "Меньше";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Random_Number;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  Random_Number = ...
}
```